# Cannot access grokdebugger in Kibana 6 on FreeBSD 11

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-grok, elasticsearch-x-pack

It appears that my kibana installation did not contain the grokdebugger plugin since I was not able to `find` it in `/usr/local/www/kibana6/` and it did not appear under the Dev Tools pane.

I did install it by installing `x-pack` using `elasticsearch-plugin` and `kibana-plugin`. This required removing a few of these x-pack plugins after installation since they were reported as being red status upon visiting the Kibana page. However, I successfully removed them and Kibana loads as normal; but there is no grokdebugger. The grokdebugger source directory is present in `/usr/local/www/kibana6/plugins/x-pack/plugins/`, and its contents appear to be normal, but it does not appear in the Dev Tools section.

I would rather consult some experts before diving too much deeper and messing things up (more than I already have).

It is worth mentioning, this is a new installation so I am open to deleting anything or installing anything from scratch if that is cleaner or easiest.

Thanks~

Edit

I've noticed that only a few of the plugins that are in `src/core_plugins` are loaded, according to the logs:

```
elasticsearch
kibana
timelion
metrics
console
```

There are numerous other plugins in that directory which are not being loaded. I tried placing `grokdebugger` in there from where it was in `plugins/x-pack`,  but it also was not picked up.

Comment: How did you install it? I guess with the tar.gz? Which version specifically? 6.2 is different than 6.3 in terms of X-Pack (which is by default already included). Generally speaking, if you use the default package of the latest 6.3 release, the Basic features (free and open code but not open source) should be included already.

Comment: Elasticsearch and Kibana were both compiled from FreeBSD ports, version 6.3. X-pack I installed using elasticsearch-plugin and kibana-plugin. The grok debugger does not appear to ever have been enabled as I have not seen it in the Dev Tools when visiting it. There is nothing that I have been able to discern in the Kibana or Elasticsearch logs about this.

Comment: I apologize, it does appear that this is actually **version 6.2.4**.

Comment: So if you are on 6.2 you'll need to install X-Pack for Elasticsearch and Kibana; you'll automatically get the trial for all commercial features and you can later on add the free Basic license, which includes Grokdebug. Why this isn't working as expected I'm honestly not sure, but I'm afraid that FreeBSD isn't officially supported. So you'll probably need more digging :(